# Resizing view to display over hidden uitabbar in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have an uitabbarcontroller which contains a couple uiViewControllers.
When i show one of those controllers i am hiding the tabbar. This view has a fullscreen uiimageView. The thing is i am seeing a white rectangle over where the tabbar is hidden.

I have tried resizing the views but the white rectangle is still there. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fullscreen in the tabbar or for the entire viewport of the device? The rectangle is there because one of your views is not positioned correctly.

Validate that your UITabBarController and/or UIViewController is set to the correct size and the correct position on the screen.